# Data binding not working correctly when observed variable is located in MainWindow.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am confused about my data binding not working correctly when observed variable is located in ***MainWindow.cs***, despite working correctly in different class. I have found out, that the problem is caused by different behavior of this piece of code:

```
public bool AccountIsSelected { get { return accountIsSelected; } set { accountIsSelected = value; OnAccountIsSelectedChanged(); } }
    private bool accountIsSelected;

    public event EventHandler AccountIsSelectedChanged;                                                                                     

    public void OnAccountIsSelectedChanged()
    {
        if (AccountIsSelectedChanged != null)                   //this stays null in MainWindow
            AccountIsSelectedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Some buttons ***IsEnabled*** property in ***MainWindow*** is bound to variable ***AccountIsSelected***.
If the variable is placed in some class other than ***MainWindow***, this class is instanciated in ***MainWindow*** and class instance is set as ***DataContext***, binding of buttons ***IsEnabled*** property works fine, because ***AccountIsSelectedChanged*** is not null.
However, if the variable is placed in ***MainWindow*** (and ***DataContext*** set to ***this)***, databinding does not work, because of ***AccountIsSelectedChanged*** staying always null.

I need the observed variable to be located in MainWindow, how do I make notification work?

Thanking in advance for any help...

Comment: `AccountIsSelectedChanged` would only work for a [static property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/whats-new#static_properties). For a non-static property, you either need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or declare a dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens, AccountIsSelectedChanged works for instance property as well. Did a dry test myself, just come to know about it. Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in MainWindow class to make the change notification effective.

There are plenty of samples online on how to implement this interface.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```

Comment: OK, why is the interface implementation not needed when bound property is placed in different class, which instance in MainWindow is set as DataContext then<

Comment: I do not have answer for it. May be this is bug. So far my understanding was  'AccountIsSelectedChanged' works for only static property. But by helping you today, with your sample, I come to know that it works for instance property as well as long as it is defined in different class.